# Amazon Alexa Custom skill: Respond to intent using standard short sound

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I'm developing a custom skill. For communication with Alexa, I use Amazon Echo Dot device. Sometimes Alexa answers with a standard short sound in the end. For example, if a session is closed because there was no answer on a question (EXCEEDED_MAX_REPROMPTS) or when some error occurred.

**Is it possible to use standard short sounds in response on my custom intents and, if so, how?**

Answer (score 0):

yes if you are using 'alexa-app' module you can use the following code:

```
  yourSkill.error= function(exception, request, response) {

  response.say('Sorry an error occured ' + error.message);
  };
```